# Remove top separator line in ListView

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have the following code:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            SearchBar(text: $searchText, placeholder: "Place Holder")
                .background(Color.white)
                .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))

            ForEach(myList, id: \.self) { element in
                Text("Hi there")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to remove the top line that I'm not even sure where it belongs to:

[image]

Any clue? I'm supporting from iOS 13.

Edit:

It seems to be part of the Cell:

[image]

Comment: Probably coming from navigationbar. try to hide the navigationBar and then check.

Comment: It seems to be part of the cell. I edited my question and added more information.

Comment: Your search bar is within the List view. Each View within List View is wrapped in its own cell. You can try to move the search view out of the list view into the VStack right before the List view.

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use `listStyle()`, I found that concrete listStyle that system provide and also not having divider between row content is `SidebarListStyle())`.

Using this,

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
            List {
                SearchBar(text: $searchText, placeholder: "Place Holder")
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))

                ForEach(myList, id: \.self) { element in
                    Text("Hi there")
                    Divider()
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }
}
```